# Permanent Redirect to another URL

Tags: apache-2.2, shell

I had a user http://www.example.com/forums for many years and very well index in the search engine. I have moved this to subdomain http://community.example.com and created another website example.com. Now how can I created permanent redirect for all the old indexing that I have in the search engine to go to the new address.

I found about 301 redirect in .htaccess but not sure how to do it.

Can you please advise?

I am on Linux with apache.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `.htaccess`.
Htaccess redirect is better(faster) than the meta refresh or PHP redirect.

To redirect all pages, add the following to the `.htaccess` in the `forums` directory of `http://www.example.com/`

```
Redirect 301 / http://community.example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're keeping the same file structure as your old site, I believe you can just do

```
Redirect 301 /forums http://community.example.com/
```